# Events for reaching the beginning/end of a series?

Tags: anychart

Trying dynamically load data from the back-end as the user reaches the end or the beginning of a series (populated via table data). The [scroller events](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Scroller#events) don't fire when "scrollOnMouseWheel" chart interactivity is enabled or when the chart is manually panned. Ideally an event would fire when the chart reaches the end or the beginning of the series independent of how the user got there (keyboard, mouse, range selection, programmatically etc..). Not seeing any overall chart events or series events in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the "[selectedrange" events](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Scroller#events) is what I was looking for. "selectedrangechangefinish " finish does fire when you pan or scroll.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, the "selectedrangechangefinish" event dispatches when you release the mouse button and finish the scroller change, on mouseUp event. All the available stock event types can be found [here](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.enums.EventType#category-stock-event-types) along with the usage samples.